# How to make tab active on page - HTML & Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Below is an HTML table contained in a tab. Now the issue i am facing is, on page load, the selected teams are supposed to show checked in the table. This is what i have noticed in my application.

For user 1, on page load the first tab is active with the checked team also  showing.

For user 2 and other users, the first tab is not active until i click on the tab before the table shows with the checked team?

I am thinking this is happening because of the `$key` in there. I actually can't tell why.. Any help will be appreciated .. Thanks

```
      <div  class="nav-tabs-custom">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($countries as $country)

           <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$country->name!!}</a></li>
           @endforeach

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)

        <div class="tab-pane {{ $key==0 ? 'active' : ''}}" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr> 
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                 </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody id="team_list">
          @foreach($country->teams as $team)
                             <tr>
                           <td>  <input onclick="return team(this)" data-team="{{$team->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $team->id !!}" name="{!! $team->name !!}" value="{!! $team->value !!}"  @foreach ($town->teams as $active_teams)   @if($team->id == $active_teams->id    ) checked @endif @endforeach  /></td>
                                    <td>{{$team->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $team->value}}</td>
                                </tr>
          @endforeach       
       </tbody>
       </table>

         </div>
        @endforeach     
          </div>    

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: That is normal, as you are setting active for this tab only for the key "0".

Comment: @MosCH that is not what i am expecting anyway.  But why is it active for just one user and not all users?

Comment: For the first user, the key is 0, and if you look in your code you can see that :)

Comment: @MosCH yeah sure. but how do i fix this? i want it to be active for all users

Comment: Besides, i am still not seeing how the key is referring to my users. i thought it refers to my categories

Comment: You made this test {{ $key==0 ? 'active' : ''}}, and as the user 1 is the first one in your countries list, then he has the key 0

Comment: @MosCH ooh okay.. how do i set the key for all users then?

Comment: In PHP, by default, the list starts with 0, so the user 1 has the key 0, the user 2 has the key 1 ..etc

Comment: got it working thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In PHP, by default, the list starts with 0, so the user 1 has the key 0, the user 2 has the key 1 ..etc
That is why you have the "user 1" only selected.